# Flows on manifolds

Tags: analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds

I am struggling with the following:

Let $M$ be a manifold and $X$ a vector field on $M$. If $c:I\rightarrow M$ is a maximal integral curve of the vector field $X$. Then there does not exists a compact subset $K\subset M$ suchthat $c(I)\subset K$ whenever $I\neq \mathbb R$ holds.

Can someone give me some tips?

Comment: Let $x$ be the first positive element of $\Bbb R$ not in $I$. Use the compactness assumption to extend past $x$. (Hint: pick a sequence of points in $I$ limiting towards $x$...)

Comment: Something looks odd about the question as stated. For example, what if $M$ is compact and $K = M$?